# Selecting multiple field values using range in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, sql, expression, select-by-attribute

I have a shape of contour lines that I need to filter using the Height Above Sea Level like this: contour lines from 500 to 1200 and from 2000 to 2500.

I can do it in several steps generating a shape using the first condition and another shape using the second, and finally combining them using these expressions:

- `"ALTURA_SOB" >= 500 AND "ALTURA_SOB" <= 1200`
- `"ALTURA_SOB" >= 2000 AND "ALTURA_SOB" <= 2500`

Nevertheless, I want to know if there is a way to do it in one step using the "Select by Expression" tool?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use this expression:

```sql
("ALTURA_SOB" >=500 AND  "ALTURA_SOB" <= 1200) OR ("ALTURA_SOB" >=2000 AND  "ALTURA_SOB" <= 2500)
```